# Sample (working) configuration for openvpn in AWS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to set up openvpn on AWS EC2 instance and I'm having lots of trouble with that... I followed the guide [on ubuntu help center](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/serverguide/openvpn.html) but it either blocks all connections or doesn't work outside the local server.

If someone could be kind enough to post their working server.conf that doesn't forward all traffic through the vpn that would be awesome.

Yes i tried the OpenVPN Access server but I need more than 2 users (and I don't want to pay for it)

Answer (score 1):

When I needed openvpn, I used a very simple configuration. The point of it was simply to connect two computers as though they were on the same network without diverting all my traffic across. The end result was that all normal traffic went through the primary connection and only traffic meant for the remote machine went to that machine.

I set up the remote machine as the server and used this conf:

server.ovpn

```
dev tap
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
secret static.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
comp-lzo
```

And the client connected with this conf:

client.conf

```
proto tcp-client
remote <remote server IP address>
dev tap
ifconfig 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0
secret /path/to/static.key
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
comp-lzo
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
```